# Assembly: Define a word in 32 bit (Intel + NASM)

Tags: assembly, debian, nasm, 32-bit, intel-syntax

I have a old assembly code in 16 bits and I want to "translate" it into a new 32 bit code for NASM.

In the old 16 bit code the words are defined as:

```
dseg            segment para public 'data'
i word ?
j word ?
```

**Now I would like to define " i " & " j " in the new 32 bit code.**

```
    SECTION .data
```

This is how I am defining .data section and I belive this is the right way, but I would like some help with the word thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SECTION .data
i dw 1
j dw 2
```

**I believe I found the right solution for this.**

" j " as a variable name, " dw " for the size of 2 bytes, and " 1 " as for the value
.

Comment: `1` is value of defined word. Location is assigned to it by assembler + linker + OS loader. `j` is label pointing to the first byte of word value `2`. Not sure what "variable" should mean, doesn't make much sense in nasm. Also keep using colons even for these labels ahead of data, like `j: dw 2`. It will prevent you to hit some ambivalent parsing bugs, like doing by accident `loop db 1` (`loop` is x86 instruction, confusing nasm. `loop: db 1` will be compiled correctly as label)

Comment: @Ped7g Thank you for the information, I will edit the answer. Will sure use this tips in the code.

Comment: Using `i` and `j` for static variable names in assembly is just as bad style as using global `int i` in a C program.  Also, depending on how you're porting this code from 16-bit, you might want to define 32-bit DWORD values (with `dd`) so you can store a 32-bit register there.  If you know your values will still fit in 16 bits, you can use 16-bit stores and zero or sign-extending loads like `movzx eax, [i]`

Comment: @PeterCordes Hello, this variables will be mostly used as counters later for loops. So they will be just int's.

Comment: Keep loop counters in registers.  You usually don't need to spill them to memory at all (and should try to avoid it).  But if you do keep them in static storage (instead of on the stack), use a better name.

Comment: Also, in 32-bit code, an `int` is 32 bits, i.e. a dword.